# GroupBy and aggregate in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to DAX queries and trying to create a DAX query equivalent to following SQL query.

```
SELECT Year, Company, SUM(Actual Sales) as Actual, SUM(Planned Sales) as Planned
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Year, Company
```

I'm not able to take aggregate of multiple columns after groupby in DAX. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually a few ways in Power BI to do this kind of aggregation. Here are three different options with slightly different results from each other.

---

**Option 1:** Query Editor

In the query editor window, select Transform -> Group By...

[image: Group by]

... and configure it as shown below (make sure to click the Advanced option).

[image: Group by config]

This results in the below. Note - this replaces the starting table.

[image: Group by results]

---

**Option 2:** Measures

In the regular window (not the query editor used in option 1), click on Modeling -> New Measure...

[image: New measure]

... to create two measures using the formulas below.

```
Actual = SUM(Sales[Actual Sales])

Planned = SUM(Sales[Planned Sales])
```

Once those measures are created, a visual (a matrix in this case) can be created with the desired headers and values.

[image: Measure matrix]

---

**Option 3:** Columns

Similarly to option 2, click on Modeling -> New Column...

[image: New columns]

... to create two columns using the formulas below.

```
Actual = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Actual Sales]),
    FILTER(
        Sales,
        Sales[Year] = EARLIER(Sales[Year]) &&
        Sales[Company] = EARLIER(Sales[Company])
    )
)

Planned = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Planned Sales]),
    FILTER(
        Sales,
        Sales[Year] = EARLIER(Sales[Year]) &&
        Sales[Company] = EARLIER(Sales[Company])
    )
)
```

Now the aggregations are in columns that can be used report visuals.

[image: Column results]